# how do i use values of if-block outside if-block?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I want to access couple of variables from `if-block`, outside in the function

eg: i want to use `signin`, `user`

```py
@app.route('/signup', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form1 = Signup()
    if form1.validate_on_submit():
        signin = auth_py.create_user_with_email_and_password(form1.email_address.data, form1.password.data)
        user = auth_py.send_email_verification(signin['idToken'])  # for email verification

        name = form1.name.data
        username = form1.username.data
        email_address = form1.email_address.data

        return redirect(url_for('home_page'))
    if form1.errors != {}:   # if no errors occur from validators
        for err_msg in form1.errors.values():
            print(f'there was an error creating the user {err_msg}')
    database(username, name, email_address) # problem is here
    return render_template('sign-up.html', form1=form1)
```

I want to use `name`, `username` and `email_address` from `form1.validate_on_submit()` inside `database()` and i don't know how can i do that.

> NOTE: there is some code yet to be written in main program so I cannot call `database()` function inside `form1.validate_on_submit()`

Comment: What do you expect the values of `name`, `username`, and `email_address` to be if `form1.validate_on_submit()` returns `False`?

Comment: @jamesdlin i expect values to be `None`

Comment: In that case the variables won't exist at all.  One way around this is to initialize those variables to `None` at the top of the function.

Answer (score 1):

```
signin = None;
user   = None;    
    def register():
        form1 = Signup()
        if form1.validate_on_submit():
            signin = auth_py.create_user_with_email_and_password(form1.email_address.data, form1.password.data)
            user = auth_py.send_email_verification(signin['idToken'])  # for email verification
    
            name = form1.name.data
            username = form1.username.data
            email_address = form1.email_address.data
    
            return redirect(url_for('home_page'))
        if form1.errors != {}:`enter code here`
```

> Define variable outside your if-block, this way you can use the
> variables outside the if-block.

Comment: but I want values that are stored inside that variable from that if-statement

Comment: why you think the value you're assigning in if-block won't be available after execution of if block. the scope of 'signin' & 'user' is outside the if block, it will retain the value you want to assign in the if-block.

Comment: @vanditvasa The `if` block returns unconditionally.  You'll never call your `database` function at all if the `if` condition is true.

Comment: please up-vote if it helps. @vanditvasa